# Range snapshot as a popup window

Tags: excel, vba, popup

```
Option Explicit
Sub Rng_Snapshot()
 Dim rng As Range
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
 Set rng = Sheet89.Range("U14:AU61")
 
 rng.CopyPicture
 
 On Error Resume Next
 
 Sheet4.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
 
 Set rng = Nothing
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

I'm using the above code to create a snapshot of a range of cells and paste it into a separate sheet. Is there any way of modifying it so it displays the snapshot as a popup window in front of everything else ?

Comment: A couple of alternatives: you can paste it as an image or you can display it in a userform

Comment: sorry to sound dim, but how would i go about displaying it as a userform ? they're not things i've used before

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/display-a-range-of-cells-from-a-worksheet-on-a-userform.566836/

Comment: Thanks, will try that

Comment: i can't get this to work

Answer (score 0):

For a quick & dirty solution, you could simply paste the picture somewhere and wait a couple of seconds before deleting it again. (Used bitmap for the opaque background). There's a limit on how big the picture can be though, and it depends what else you have going on on the screen.

```
Range("D13:AF58").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A99")
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.7, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Range("A99").Show
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Selection.Delete
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```